# create a snapshot table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

May you please assist,

I am currently working on a daily report to be distributed  to users via email. The report is looking at a date range month to date, e.g. if today is 11th the report should give me details from the 1st till the 10th.

On that note the data on the report can change on a daily basis, it might happen that say yesterday(10th Feb) statistics was 100, and today for the same day(10th Feb) might show an increase or decrease(10th Feb Statistics = 102 or 10th Feb Statistics = 98).

Now I need to keep the snapshot in a table, of which I can be able to compare statistics on a daily basis. I need this to be an automated process, whereby when the reports immediately finish executing, then data being reported can be saved in a table.

If you know of the best way I can use, I would appreciate it if you share your knowledge.

Regards

Comment: Can you not just insert the results into a table with a date column so you know when they were generated?

Comment: hey there thing is this is retrieves a large amount of data about 30 thousands a day , yes that option is the one to do. but now i need to ensure that whatever method i use will not take longer to be executed. i need an effective method that i can use. cos i have been doing a simple insert and it takes super long to execute

Comment: hey there most definitely, that's exactly what i need to do, now my issue is i have  large amount of data to insert into my history table and retrieve for the report. i have a simple insert of retrieving data putting into a temp table insert into the table and  retrieve data for the report. my only issue is this takes super long to do so. now i want to use the most effective and fast solution possible because I need to sent out this as an automated report for users via email.